# Azure function to calculate md5 checksum

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, md5

I'm trying to calculate the md5 checksum of a file that I submit through a POST request with a Java based Azure function. However, when I submit the file as a String as part of the request, it contains some header information that keeps changing (not sure why), and therefore the md5 checksum keeps changing with each request.

```
public class Function {
/**
 * This function listens at endpoint "/api/HttpExample". Two ways to invoke it using "curl" command in bash:
 * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/HttpExample
 * 2. curl "{your host}/api/HttpExample?name=HTTP%20Query"
 * @throws IOException
 */
@FunctionName("HttpExample")
public HttpResponseMessage run(
        @HttpTrigger(
            name = "req",
            methods = {HttpMethod.POST},
            authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
            HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request, 
        final ExecutionContext context) throws IOException {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

    // Parse query parameter
    final String content = request.getBody().get();
    context.getLogger().info(content);

    byte[] md5Bytes = DigestUtils.md5(content);
    String md5 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(md5Bytes);
    

    if (md5 == null) {
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name in the request body").build();
    } else {
        return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body(md5).build();
    }
}
```

}

below is the output of the logging statement above for two different requests (for the same tmp.txt file):

```
[2022-01-25T11:25:50.663Z] ----------------------------657892529889811456400753
[2022-01-25T11:25:50.664Z] Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="tmp.txt"
[2022-01-25T11:25:50.664Z] Content-Type: text/plain
[2022-01-25T11:25:50.665Z] 
[2022-01-25T11:25:50.665Z] abd
[2022-01-25T11:25:50.666Z] ----------------------------657892529889811456400753--
```

and

```
[2022-01-25T11:26:05.836Z] ----------------------------005234239999372220970885
[2022-01-25T11:26:05.837Z] Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="tmp.txt"
[2022-01-25T11:26:05.838Z] Content-Type: text/plain
[2022-01-25T11:26:05.838Z] 
[2022-01-25T11:26:05.838Z] abd
[2022-01-25T11:26:05.839Z] ----------------------------005234239999372220970885--
```

since the headers differ, the resulting md5 checksum also does not match. Is there a clever way to strip only the content?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem: I'm invoking the function from Azure Logic Apps. So converting to a String first, and then passing this string to the function app works fine:

```
byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(@"filepath");
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```